# Calculating pow(45,60) mod 61

Tags: c#, c, algorithm, math

This is a homework question.

I need to calculate 45^60 mod 61. I want to know of any fast method to get the result either programmatically or manually whichever is faster.

Comment: programmatically will be faster i think. you can use C POW function and % operator to get the job done.

Comment: manually? you don't have to write any code? then ask wolfram alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=45^60+mod+61

Comment: @Tobias: that definitely will not work. 45^60 has somewhere around 320 bits, a lot more than any `double` or even `long double`.

Comment: [Calculating pow(a,b) mod n](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8496182/995714)

Answer (score 21):

The result would be 1 because of Fermat's little theorem

[image]

if `p` is prime.

61 is a prime number so `a`<sup>`p-1`</sup> when divided by `p` would give 1 as the remainder.

However if `p` is non-prime the usual trick is repeated-squaring.

Comment: +1, but `a is an integer coprime to p` should follow after if p is prime.

Comment: There are also other theorems than can be used for speeding `a^b mod p` when p is not prime and b is big.

Answer (score 6):

```
45^60 =
2025^30 = (33*61 + 12)^30 = 12^30 =
144^15 = (2*61 + 22)^15 = 22^15 =
10648^5 = ( 174*61 + 34)^5 = 34^5 =
45435424 = 744843 * 61 + 1 = 1
```

Here equality means = (mod 61)

Answer (score 4):

I would say your best bet would be to use Fermat's Little Theorem.

[Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

where p = 61 and p-1 = 60.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

```
45^2         = 2025 = 12
45^4  = 12^2 = 144  = 22
45^8  = 22^2 = 484  = 57
45^16 = 57^2 = 3249 = 16
45^32 = 16^2 = 256  = 12

45^60 = 45^(4+8+16+32) = 22 * 57 * 16 * 12 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Wolfram Alpha

Always have [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=45%5E60+mod+61) at hand :D

[image]