# How to calculate x^y mod z?

Tags: math, modulo, modular-arithmetic

I am wondering how to calculate x^y mod z. x and y are very large (can't fit in 64 bit integer) and z will fit 64 bit integer.
And one thing don't give answers like x^y mod z is same as (x mod z)^y mod z.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496182/calculating-powa-b-mod-n

Answer (score 3):

Here is the standard method, in pseudo-code:

```
function powerMod(b, e, m)
    x := 1
    while e > 0
        if e % 2 == 1
            x := (b * x) % m
            e := e - 1
        else
            b := (b * b) % m
            e := e / 2
    return x
```

The algorithm is known as *exponentiation by squaring* or the *square and multiply* method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java, then turn x, y, and z into BigInteger.

```
BigInteger xBI = new BigInteger(x);
BigInteger yBI = new BigInteger(y);
BigInteger zBI = new BigInteger(z);
BigInteger answer = xBI.modPow(yBI,zBI);
```