# Why python exponentiation with math.pow() yield overflow error and not with ** operator?

Tags: python, primes, pow, prime-factoring, exponentiation

this question is different from [[Exponentials in python x.**y vs math.pow(x, y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969773/exponentials-in-python-x-y-vs-math-powx-y])
because a snippet using math.pow() cannot compute result, while the ** operator can.

I am experimenting with a little snippet to compute first N doubly prime numbers with Fermat's Little theorem:

per `1<= a < n`,

if `a^n mod(n) = a mod(n)` 
then `n is a Prime`

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime)
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime)

I found that:

```
math.pow(a,n) % n == a % n
```

yields to overflow error:

```
math range error
```

for: `a = 2`, `n == 1508950`

instead with `**` operator works fine:
`2**1508950` yields ... a very, very, very long number :)

```
2**1508950 = 1629135338929954... #with 450K+ and counting digits.
```

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) states that `The two-argument form pow(x, y) is equivalent to using the power operator: x**y`.

Why this difference ?

Comment: math.pow works with floats and two "*" works with the type of operand: ie: `math.pow(2, 3)` give 8.0 and `2* *3` give 8. Instead, `pow` (built-in) works the same two "*".

Comment: Clodion your comment should be marked as answer, I was just now reading about it here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10283032/305883] : @Martijn Pieters I think this would be the appropriate reference to mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: @user305883: done.

Comment: You should use the optional third argument to the `pow` function: `pow(x,y,m)` is equivalent to `pow(x,y)%m`, but all the calculations are done mod _m_ and will not involve the large intermediate numbers.

Comment: @user448810 yes I tried that, I would like to better understand which is the difference in time complexity (big O notation) between the two implementation: how does python handle the two operations without "involving the large intermediate numbers"? I also tried `pow(a,n, n) == a % n` which is different then `b = pow(a,n, n) if b == (a % n) : // do something` : it looks like the first is computed "on the fly" with "no need to store in memory".

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28140940/448810). That answer uses a method called [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), except that all multiplications are done using modular arithmetic.