# Why is large number power timing out in Elixir?

Tags: performance, elixir, bitcoin

I am trying to recreate some basics of Bitcoin in Elixir. I know Elixir is not the ideal language for the task but I am doing this for fun and learning purposes. I have run into the following problem when trying to implement public key derivation from a secret, which includes a very large power on a very large number over a finite field. I implemented this myself given that :math.pow/2 is struggling with comparably small numbers already. But my implementation is taking extremely long and the function eventually times out.

Values and calling the function:

```
prime = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
val = 65341020041517633956166170261014086368942546761318486551877808671514674964848

Util.my_fpow(val, prime - 2, prime)
```

my_fpow/3 method in the Util module:

```
defmodule Util do
  def my_fpow(n, k, prime), do: my_fpow(n, k, 1, prime)
  defp my_fpow(_, 0, acc, _), do: acc
  defp my_fpow(n, k, acc, prime) do
    new_acc = n * acc
              |> rem(prime)

    my_fpow(n, k - 1, new_acc, prime)
  end
end
```

First of all, I would like to understand on a deeper level why this method takes so long for these large numbers. Also I would be interested if there are other more efficient implementations that might still make it viable to do such calculations in Elixir (not at scale, just so the calculation could actually finish before timing out).

Comment: the `rem/2` function is probably your bottleneck - take a look at https://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/ which doesn't use elixir though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function will recurse `prime - 2` times since you're subtracting it by 1 at a time. Even if Elixir executes 1 billion calls per second (which it won't on current hardware), it'll take more than 10^60 years to execute.

A much faster solution [involves squaring the number on each iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496182/320615) which reduces the number of calls to `log2(x)`, which is pretty fast. Here's a translation of that algorithm:

```
defmodule A do
  # Calculates (n ^ k) % m.
  def powmod(n, k, m), do: powmod(n, k, m, 1)
  def powmod(_, 0, _, r), do: r
  def powmod(n, k, m, r) do
    r = if rem(k, 2) == 1, do: rem(r * n, m), else: r
    n = rem(n * n, m)
    k = div(k, 2)
    powmod(n, k, m, r)
  end
end

prime = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
val = 65341020041517633956166170261014086368942546761318486551877808671514674964848

IO.inspect A.powmod(val, prime - 2, prime)
```

Output:

```
83174505189910067536517124096019359197644205712500122884473429251812128958118
```

Comment: Awesome! This helped me a lot. Anyone else looking for more info on why and how this works should look here for a lengthy breakdown of the formula including python versions of the code: https://www.rookieslab.com/posts/fast-power-algorithm-exponentiation-by-squaring-cpp-python-implementation