# How to divide 2^{128} by an odd number in c++?

Tags: c++

How can we divide 2^{128} by an odd number (unsigned 64-bit integer), which is a floor more precisely, without using arbitrary multi-precision arithmetic library?

The problem is even with gcc, 2^{128} cannot be expressed.
So I'm considering creating 192-bit integer type.
But, I have no idea how to do that (especially subtraction part).
I want the result of the floor to be an unsigned number.

Comment: You can create your data type based on an array of bytes with a custom `operator/` in which you will define how your bits are operated

Comment: Do you have 128-bit arithmetic or just 64?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating pow(a,b) mod n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496182/calculating-powa-b-mod-n)

Comment: If you have 128 bit integers, see Eric's answer. If you do not, then what data type would you intend to store the answer in? Instead of writing your own, use a tried and tested one (it'll save you the work, the debugging and will most likely be faster on top of it all).

Comment: I am voting to close this question as unclear because it is missing key information, namely the data type, as Eric Postpischil already mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any odd *d* > 1, `UINT128_MAX / d` equals floor(2<sup>128</sup>/*d*).

This is because 2<sup>128</sup>/*d* must have a remainder, as the only factors of 2<sup>128</sup> are powers of two (including 1), so the odd *d* (excluding 1) cannot be a divisor. Therefore, 2<sup>128</sup>/*d* and (2<sup>128</sup>−1)/*d* have the same integral quotient, and `UINT128_MAX` is 2<sup>128</sup>−1.

Comment: It seems that your solution works simply and correctly.Thank you very much!