# Performance of Integer type with large numbers

Tags: haskell, biginteger

I'm trying to solve [AdventOfCode 2018 day 14](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/14). The task is roughly to create a number with a lot of digits by iteratively appending one or two digits based on two already existing digits. With Haskell I thought `Integer` might be a good fit for representing the huge number. I think my program is *correct*, at least it seems to work for the samples AoC provides. However I noticed that the performance of the program drops drastically when the number contains more than 10^4 digits (`recipeCount` in the appended program). I observed the following execution times when increasing the number up to the following number of digits:

- 10000 digits: 0.314s
- 20000 digits: 1.596s
- 30000 digits: 4.306s
- 40000 digits: 8.954s

Looks like `O(n^2)` or worse, doesn't it?

Why is that? The program only does *basic* calculations as far as I can tell.

```
import Data.Bool (bool)

main :: IO ()
main = print solve

recipeCount :: Int
recipeCount = 10000

solve :: Integer
solve = loop 0 1 37 2
    where
        loop recipeA recipeB recipes recipesLength
            | recipesLength >= recipeCount + 10 = recipes `rem` (10 ^ 10)
            | otherwise =
                let recipeAScore = digitAt (recipesLength - 1 - recipeA) recipes
                    recipeBScore = digitAt (recipesLength - 1 - recipeB) recipes
                    recipeSum = fromIntegral $ recipeAScore + recipeBScore
                    recipeSumDigitCount = bool 2 1 $ recipeSum < 10
                    recipes' = recipes * (10 ^ recipeSumDigitCount) + recipeSum
                    recipesLength' = recipesLength + recipeSumDigitCount
                    recipeA' = (recipeA + recipeAScore + 1) `rem` recipesLength'
                    recipeB' = (recipeB + recipeBScore + 1) `rem` recipesLength'
                in loop recipeA' recipeB' recipes' recipesLength'

digitAt :: Int -> Integer -> Int
digitAt i number = fromIntegral $ number `quot` (10 ^ i) `rem` 10
```

P.S.: Because I'm very new to Haskell I also kindly appreciate feedback on the program itself (style, algorithm, etc.).

EDIT:
I found options to profile both versions of my program.
Both versions are compiled with `ghc -O2 -rtsopts ./Program.hs` and run with `./Program +RTS -sstderr`.

The first version with integers produces the following output when generating 50,000 recipes:

```
   2,435,108,280 bytes allocated in the heap
         886,656 bytes copied during GC
          44,672 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          29,056 bytes maximum slop
               0 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1925 colls,     0 par    0.018s   0.017s     0.0000s    0.0001s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time   15.208s  ( 15.225s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.018s  (  0.017s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time   15.227s  ( 15.242s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    160,115,875 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.9% of total user, 99.9% of total elapsed
```

The second version with mutable arrays produces the following output when generating ~500,000 recipes:

```
      93,437,744 bytes allocated in the heap
          16,120 bytes copied during GC
         538,408 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          29,056 bytes maximum slop
               0 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0        88 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.021s  (  0.020s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.021s  (  0.021s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    4,552,375,284 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  97.0% of total user, 97.2% of total elapsed
```

Comment: Hint: `rem (a * b) c == rem (rem a c * rem b c) c`, so you do not need to use `Integer`s. In fact in a lot of programming contests/etc. this is something you can exploit to keep working with fixed-sized integers.

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496182/calculating-powa-b-mod-n

Comment: Thanks. But because in every iteration I'm selecting two digits (`recipeA` and `recipeB` are indices) I think I need to store the full number, right? Or how exactly would I apply your hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `Integer` for your recipes list in the first place is a big red flag. `Integer`s store numbers, but your problem does not call for a number. It calls for a list of digits. An `Integer`, whose first priority is to be a number, is basically "compressed": it's in binary, not decimal, and trying to extract a decimal digit from it means you have to do funky, nontrivial math, as others have said. Also, purity works against you, because each time you add new digits to your list, you end up copying the whole list. With problem sizes on the order of 100,000-1,000,000 digits (I was given a problem input of about 800,000), that's copying `Integer`s on the order of `log_(2^8)(10^(10^5)) = ~41000` bytes in size each time. This part also seems quadratic.

I would recommend "decompressing" your list of digits. You can represent a single digit by 1 byte (which does waste a lot of space!)

```
import Data.Word
type Digit = Word8
addDigit :: Digit -> Digit -> (Digit, Digit)
addDigit = _yourJob
```

You can implement the meat of the logic as a function using arrays. Yes, Haskell does have arrays, in the sense of contiguous hunks of memory with practically O(1) indexing. It's just that we like to find "more functional" ways to phrase a problem than with arrays. But, they're always there if you need them.

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed -- from the array package, which is a core library
makeRecipes ::
  -- | Elf 1's starting score
  Digit ->
  -- | Elf 2's starting score
  Digit ->
  -- | Number of recipes to make
  Int ->
  -- | Scores of the recipes made, indices running from 0 upwards
  UArray Int Digit
```

The cool thing about arrays is that you can mutate them inside the [`ST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) monad, while getting a pure result. Thus, this array does not suffer any copying, and the math involved for indexing it is minimal.

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
makeRecipes elf1 elf2 need = runSTUArray $ do
  arr <- newArray_ (0, need)
  writeArray arr 0 elf1
  writeArray arr 1 elf2
  loop arr 0 1 2
  return arr
  where
    loop :: STUArray s Int Digit -> Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()
    loop arr loc1 loc2 done = _yourJob
```

`loop` is given the array, which is partially filled with `done` recipe scores, and the locations of the two elves, `loc1, loc2 < done`. It should calculate the new recipes' scores with `addDigit` and [`readArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:readArray) and add them to the array at the correct location with `writeArray`. If the array is full, it should terminate (it doesn't return anything useful). Otherwise, it should go on to figure out the new locations of the elves, and then recurse.

You can then write a little adapter on top of `makeRecipes` to actually extract the last ten recipes, supply the correct inputs, etc. When I filled in all the blanks in the program, I got a runtime of .07s on my input (about 800,000) with `-O2`, and about 0.8s with `-O0`. It seems to take `O(n)` time in the input.

Comment: You're totally right. I probably thought of `Integer`s as a compressed version of `[Int]`. In the meantime I rewrote my version using normal arrays (from `Data.Array`) but I roughly get the same result, which might be due to too much copying as you said.

Comment: @JohannesEgger That seems plausible, as with `UArray` I can get up to 800,000 in (almost?) imperceptible time. In that case, it seems like the actual math operations aren't as expensive as the copying.

Comment: Wow, I just implemented your fancy suggestion and I get numbers similar to yours (500,000 digits in less than 0.5 seconds). Thanks a lot .